# DynamoDBMappingException on mapping Map<String, Object>attribute

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am trying to save the instance of the class bellow into dynamdb but getting
`DynamoDBMappingException: not supported; requires @DynamoDBTyped or @DynamoDBTypeConverted` exception.

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "FulfillmentOrders")
public class FulfillmentOrder {

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    private String orderId;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    @DynamoDBTyped(value = DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.DynamoDBAttributeType.M)
    private Map<String, Object> body;

    ....... 
}
```

It fails during map conversion, seems the problem is in Object generic type.

could someone help, where is the problem here or maybe SDK doesn't support such kind of conversion ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DynamoDB won't know how to convert the `object`s in the `Map<,>`, you'll have to create a custom type converter. once you've done this you can annotate the prooperty with `@DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = xxx)`:

In your example:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "FulfillmentOrders")
public class FulfillmentOrder {

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    private String orderId;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    @DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = BodyTypeConverter.class)
    private Map<String, Object> body;
}


static public class BodyTypeConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, Map<String, Object>> {

    @Override
    public String convert(Map<String, Object> object) {
        DimensionType itemDimensions = (Map<String, Object>) object;

        // Convert the object to a DynamoDB json string
        String json = "wibble";

        return json;
    }

    @Override
    public DimensionType unconvert(String s) {
        Map<String, Object> item = new Map<String, Object>();

        // Convert s to a Map<String, Object> here.

        return item;
    }
}
```

More information can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.ArbitraryDataMapping.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kevin! So from your answer it means that the body attribute in DynamoDb should of String type instead of Map right ? In my case it's Map type.

Comment: String is just one of many types that DynamoDB supports, as long as you map in to a supported type you'll be fine (Here's a list of supported types https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.DataTypes.html)

Comment: In the case when body attribute will have String type, this solution works fine. But if the type is Map (document) a conversion fails.It seems that if I want to have a document type I should have mirroring POJO, Map<String, Object> will not work in that case.

Comment: That's because it doesn't know how to map `Object` to a DynamoDB type. Thus you have to tell it how to map your `Object`

Comment: Yes, that's the point. Values of the map can be have any DynamoDB supported type. Do you have some example for this case?
Thank you Kevin!

Comment: I've only got examples in C# but they work the same, All you need to do is convert your `Object` in your map to something that DynamoDB can deal with